# Dynamic SQL code to convert rows to columns

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a table in MySQL like this:

```
+-------+----------+
|  am   | ipiresia |
+-------+----------+
| 50470 |       29 |
| 50470 |       43 |
| 50433 |       29 |
|  6417 |       51 |
|  6417 |       52 |
|  6417 |       53 |
|  4960 |       25 |
|  4960 |       26 |
|  5567 |       89 |
|  6716 |       88 |
+-------+----------+
```

I want to transform it like this:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  am   | ipiresia1 | ipiresia2 | ipiresia3 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 50470 |        29 |        43 |           |
| 50433 |        29 |           |           |
|  6417 |        51 |        52 |        53 |
|  4960 |        25 |        26 |           |
|  5567 |        89 |           |           |
|  6716 |        88 |           |           |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Of course this is only a part of the table. The max occurrences of 'ipiresia' per 'am' can be up to 5, so I think a dynamic pivot table could do the work but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Isn't it more feasible to write a php (or whatever language) script that does this (you said transform and I assume this is permanent then) ? Run it once and you are done.

Comment: When I say transform I mean to create a query to get the data in different way.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but something like [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) might be a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - add one more column with an exact `ipiresia` number -

```
+-------+----------+-----+
|  am   | ipiresia | num |
+-------+----------+-----+
| 50470 |       29 |   1 |
| 50470 |       43 |   2 |
| 50433 |       29 |   1 |
|  6417 |       51 |   1 |
|  6417 |       52 |   2 |
|  6417 |       53 |   3 |
|  4960 |       25 |   1 |
|  4960 |       26 |   2 |
|  5567 |       89 |   1 |
|  6716 |       88 |   1 |
+-------+----------+-----+
```

Then use dynamic pivot -

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(num = ''',
      num,
      ''', ipiresia, NULL)) AS ',
      CONCAT('ipiresia', num)
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM ipiresia;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT am, ', @sql, ' FROM ipiresia GROUP BY am');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Result -

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| am    | ipiresia1 | ipiresia2 | ipiresia3 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  4960 |        25 |        26 |      NULL |
|  5567 |        89 |      NULL |      NULL |
|  6417 |        51 |        52 |        53 |
|  6716 |        88 |      NULL |      NULL |
| 50433 |        29 |      NULL |      NULL |
| 50470 |        29 |        43 |      NULL |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

[Automate pivot table queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=523)

[Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)

Comment: Thanks Devart :-) Your sql script did the trick. Now the only thing is to create the column with the 'ipiresia' number in the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

Like Orangepill suggested, group concat is the answer here, but you will have the ipiresia result in one column :

```
SELECT am, GROUP_CONCAT(ipiresia)
FROM table
GROUP BY am
```

You should have something like

```
+-------+-----------+
|  am   | ipiresia  | 
+-------+-----------+
| 50470 |    29, 43 |
| 50433 |        29 |
|  6417 | 51, 52, 53|
|  4960 |    25, 26 |
|  5567 |        89 |
|  6716 |        88 |
+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Yes, but I want them in different columns. Unfortunately this does not cover my needs.